# CSS Responsive HTML forms

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML Code:

```
<h4>Company Details</h4>

<div>
    <label for="company">Company</label>

    <div>
        <input type="text" name="company" value="<?php echo $customer["company"]; ?>" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to have the text inputs and labels displaying inline with each other then as the screen gets smaller to move the text inputs under the labels

Comment: Are you using bootstrap? http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: @K.B.M What does bootstrap have to do with anything?

Comment: Yeah, why not use a whole framework to replace two lines of CSS?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this. Chose the one that fits your project the best. I would set the label and the div containing the input as "inline" or "inline-block" using CSS. Then if you need then line to collapse into two, use media queries (see the last code snippet).

```
<h4>Company Details</h4>
<div class="input-group">
    <label for="company">Company</label>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="company" value="<?php echo $customer["company"]; ?>" />
    </div>
</div>

// This will make them show inline occupying half the width
.input-group > label, .input-group > div{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
}
```

I sometimes have problems with extra pixels in inline-blocks,
and I typically solve it by floating the blocks or setting the
font size to zero.

```
// This way the label and input float
.input-group {
    clear: both; // So the container doesn't collapse
}
.input-group > label, .input-group > div{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
```

For the font size version:

```
// This way the font size in the container is zero
.input-group {
    font-size: 0;
}
.input-group > label, .input-group > div{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Your `div` will automatically stretch to 100% of the screen, so You don't need media queries to set its width; it's already responsive as is. But if you insist on using them, or need them, add this as well:

```
@media (max-width: 500px) {
    .input-group > label, .input-group > div{
        display: block;
        float: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy to achieve. Simply set:

```
.inputLine label, .inputLine div {
    display: inline;
}
```

With the HTML being:

```
<h4>Company Details</h4>

<div class="inputLine">
    <label for="company">Company</label>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="company" value="My Company" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/wLjekogo/

---

Updated: april 20th, 2015

To achieve the requested output, while allowing multiple inline elements. You could use the following HTML/CSS combination:

HTML

```
<h4>Company Details</h4>

<div class="inputLine">
    <label for="company">Company</label>
    <input type="text" name="company" value="My Company" />
</div>

<div class="inputLine">
    <label for="company">Company</label>
    <input type="text" name="company" value="My Company" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.inputLine {
    display: inline-block;
}

.inputLine label {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: "100%";
}

.inputLine input {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
}
```

This would show all input fields inline, unless the screen is too small. In which case first the divs will be on a new line, and even more smaller, a vertical form.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/wLjekogo/2/

Comment: @larrssy1 Why using a `div` element to set it `inline` ?

Comment: It's his source code, where he wraps the input inside the div, I simply made it work with a small change. Just remember that if you don't wrap it in a div (which could be a container for more form elements), that you'll have to create a stylesheet for all elements. If it would only be for input fields, than ofcourse the div would be optional.

Comment: In that case, to group inline elements, I would tend to use a `span` element... But that's okay if you look for a small change.

Comment: check this updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/wLjekogo/1/ it doesn't put them under each other if i have multiple text inputs

Comment: Updated the answer. I think it now does as you requested. It's pretty much how bootstrap works. If you'd like a truly responsive website, you could consider using Bootstrap.